# 15.10 64bit steam Xerror

Tags: drivers, ati, steam

I have Ubuntu 15.10 64bit running on my laptop and have the default open source drivers installed (the proprietary drivers break my system). When I try and run steam in the terminal I get the error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2015-12-25 18:15:19] Startup - updater built Dec 14 2015 11:15:53
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occured
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

The terminal hangs up at this point and I need to CTRL-C to exit steam.

I think steam wants to use the proprietary drivers to run, but the those drivers break the system. ATI

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Mircro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470]
```

Answer (score 0):

ATI/AMD drivers don't support ubuntu 15.10 (really support 15.10, but don't support kernel version after 3.19) 
U need to wait fix/new version of drivers with 4.x kernel support.
Or downgrade to 14.04 LTS =)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

I found these solutions which worked for me.

1. Copy/Paste these commands in the terminal after you get your error:

   ```
   rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
   rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
   rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
   ```

OR

2. Install steam through Wine & playOnLinux ( this will install the windows version, the native steam app is better in my opinion but if it really won't launch this could be an acceptable solution)

It is explained very well on this forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2315531

I hope this helps!